# Multiple defination error while compiling Marlin using platformio

Tags: multiple-definition-error, platformio

Recently updated to Marlin 2.0.6.1, because the compiler won't work with 2.0.6 anymore. Updated the platformio as well. Now when I compile I get these errors, mostly multiple defination kinds, before it used to compile with no problems. If anyone know how to fix them I would really appreciate it.

```
At top level:
C:\users\administrator\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoststm32-maple\STM32F1\libraries\FreeRTOS701\utility\port.c:285:6: warning: 'prvSetupTimerInterrupt' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 void prvSetupTimerInterrupt( void )
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Archiving .pio\build\mks_robin_e3\lib91f\libFreeRTOS701.a
Archiving .pio\build\mks_robin_e3\libe21\libServo.a
Archiving .pio\build\mks_robin_e3\lib6b5\libU8glib-HAL_ID1932@0.4.1.a
Linking .pio\build\mks_robin_e3\firmware.elf
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::datasize()':
C:\users\administrator\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoststm32-maple\STM32F1\cores\maple/HardwareSerial.h:145: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::datasize()'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:C:\users\administrator\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoststm32-maple\STM32F1\cores\maple/HardwareSerial.h:145: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::postprocess()':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:448: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::postprocess()'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:422: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::size_error(unsigned short)':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:564: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::size_error(unsigned short)'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:538: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::save()':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:575: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::save()'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:549: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::reset()':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:2437: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::reset()'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:2372: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `say_M569(bool, char const*, bool)':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:2860: multiple definition of `say_M569(bool, char const*, bool)'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:2782: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::report(bool)':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:2899: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::report(bool)'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:2821: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::_load()':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:1424: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::_load()'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:1377: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::validate()':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:2303: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::validate()'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:2238: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o: In function `MarlinSettings::load()':
L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:2317: multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::load()'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:2252: first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o:(.bss._ZN14MarlinSettings10validatingE+0x0): multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::validating'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:(.bss._ZN14MarlinSettings10validatingE+0x0): first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o:(.bss._ZN14MarlinSettings12eeprom_errorE+0x0): multiple definition of `MarlinSettings::eeprom_error'  
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:(.bss._ZN14MarlinSettings12eeprom_errorE+0x0): first defined here
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/settings.cpp:445: multiple definition of `new_z_fade_height'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:L:\3dPrinter\Marlin-2.0.x/Marlin\src\module/configuration_store.cpp:419: first defined here.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/settings.cpp.o:(.bss.settings+0x0): multiple definition of `settings'
.pio/build/mks_robin_e3/src/src/module/configuration_store.cpp.o:(.bss.settings+0x0): first defined here
```